# Vagrant 2.0.1 VBox 5.2.6, Errors when running vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have been following the vagrant [Getting Started Guide](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/).

I had a problem where vagrant would freeze my entire machine when using `vagrant up`, so I did what was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994926/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-on-vagrant-up) (scroll down towards the bottom to a post by Valross.nu).

I have Vagrant 2.0.1 and VirtualBox 5.2.6 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

When running `vagrant init`, `vagrant up`, or pretty much any other command, I get the following errors:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:293:in `read': Input/output error @ rb_sysopen - /home/patrick/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index (Errno::EIO)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:293:in `read'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:293:in `unlocked_reload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:53:in `block in initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:323:in `block in with_index_lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:321:in `open'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:321:in `with_index_lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:52:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:741:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:741:in `machine_index'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:215:in `block in action_runner'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:543:in `hook'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `unload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:141:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:141:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Having same issue. Any fix?

Comment: Sadly not yet..

Comment: Can you launch VirtualBox machine manually and start the machine manually and see if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue.

1. Delete `vagrant.d` directory from your working directory.
2. run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I choose to accept this answer because it solves the problem and lets me use the most up to date software!

I was able to ssh into my vagrant vm.

Comment: Also, mind explaining why this solves the problem? I'd really like to know.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be somebody else running into the same issue at https://superuser.com/questions/1286465/vagrant-and-virtualbox-suddenly-don-t-work-for-me-on-ubuntu-16-04-3.

I wrote this in as a comment there as well, but I noticed that 
VirtualBox had a new release on Jan 15; have you considered downgrading just VirtualBox? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog
(Vagrant was last updated on Nov 2 which was longer ago, hence my suggestion to focus on VirtualBox. https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/releases)

If it were me, I'd major try downgrading both Vagrant and Virtualbox just a little (eg, maybe still Vagrant 2.0.x and VBox 5.2.x), and if I were still running into issues, further downgrades to Vagrant 1.9.x and VBox 5.1.x.

If this works, then "it works good enough" might be fine (and potentially desired at a workplace) unless you absolutely need any cutting edge features that may happen to be in the latest versions.